# Excel Formula required for Date Calculation

Tags: excel, formula

Required MS Excel formula for date calculation as below stated. Need answer like 31years 7months 6 days.

[image]

Required MS Excel formula for date calculation as below stated. Need answer like 31years 7months 6 days.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Dominique, I have tried with Datedif but vain

Comment: Use helper column to separate years, months and days and the sum up all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the cleanest way, maybe with advanced functions of Excel 365 you can get this on a single formula, but not on older versions. You need helper columns to calculate everything (but you coould hide them and just show the final results:

[image]

I'm using 3 helper columns (years, months, days):

[image]

Cell C7: `=DATEDIF(A7;B7;"Y")`

Cell D7: `=DATEDIF(EDATE(A7;C7*12);B7;"M")`

Cell E7: `=B7-EDATE(EDATE(A7;C7*12);D7)`

Cell F7: `=C7&" years "&D7&" months " & E7 & " days"`

Just drag down.

Then for grand total in row 2:

Cell C2: `=SUM(C7:C8)+INT(SUM(D7:D8)/12)`

Cell D2: `=MOD(SUM(D7:D8);12)`

Cell E2: `=SUM(E7:E8)`

Cell F2: `=C2&" years "&D2&" months " & E2 & " days"`

As I said, not the cleanest but if gets the work done.

Please, note my argument separator in functions is the semicolon `;`. Depending on your regional settings you may need comma `,` instead of `;`

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps

`=TEXTJOIN(" ",,DATEDIF(A1,B1,{"y";"ym";"md"})&" "&{"years";"months";"days"})`

though with the caveat that the official MS documentation for the `DATEDIF` function states that use of the "md" parameter can lead to inaccurate results.

Comment: I am searching the answer for 14 years 9 months 0 days + 16 years 10 months 6 days, which should be 31years 7 months 6 days, I am seeking for the formula to get 31 years 7 months 6 days

Comment: You'd need to clarify your expected result for a case such as `14 years 9 months 18 days + 16 years 10 months 15 days`. Does this become `31 years 8 months 2 days`? Or `31 years 8 months 3 days`? Or something else?